# How can I use Url.Action and Html.ActionLink when my application is pointed somewhere else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC application hosted on apps.server.com/appname but I have a URL rewrite being done on my company's F5 that makes that application visible to www.server.com/apps/appname.  Now when I navigate to that url no images or links work because they are all pointing to www.server.com/appname when using @Url.Content("~/URL").  What do I need to do for all of my helper classes to know that I am under an aliased URL instead of where it thinks it is (ie, the apps.server.com URL)?

Comment: It's usually better, if there some form of re-write happening, to let the re-writer handle modifying the response also, rather than doing half of the re-writing in the re-writer, and half in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in IIS 7 Integrated Pipeline mode try putting the following in your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Request.ServerVariables.Remove("IIS_WasUrlRewritten");
}
```