# Bundle Config relative path added controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, assets, relative-path

Sorry for my English...
I have a problem with BundleCOnfig...

I added new script bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
           "~/assets/js/progress-bar/src/jquery.velocity.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/progress-bar/number-pb.js",
            "~/assets/js/progress-bar/progress-app.js",
            "~/assets/js/preloader.js",
            "~/assets/js/bootstrap.js",
            "~/assets/js/app.js",
            "~/assets/js/load.js",
            "~/assets/js/main.js"));
```

And add this code to _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
```

When I load page at localhost:21612/ no errors occur. Page displayed correctly:

[Normal load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO07G.png)

But if I load page at localhost:21612/Home/Index I get errors. And in path is added controller names:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2s43.png)

I do not understand what the problem is, because the relative path to the script, why is inserted controller name?

**UPDATE:** Problem solved. The fact is that in the file main.js, all the way to the other scripts were installed as src="assets/, and should be src="/assets/

Answer (score 0):

The tilde has changed in MVC5 to do clever things with URL rewriting.  I don't understand why it's doing this to you but if you're doing any URL rewriting, you can turn off overly clever fixing of on-page URLS, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12105210/7353829

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem was of absolute paths in main.js file. I updated my post.